# Getting facebook group id from group url

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-group

i have tried to get facebook group id (gid) by it's url using C#, with no luck.
I have looked over the facebook graph tables, tried PHP, FQL queries, and even tried P3P to get the feed itself of the group page (To get the 'cid' value) - But again - with no luck, I'm getting a token successfully using facebook SDK but I dont understand how to use it to get the group id or the group source code (which always returns the login page), can you help ?

Comment: Can you give an example of the group url

Comment: For example: https://www.facebook.com/groups/progressivenagars

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the username from the url- string after last `/`. You can find how to do that. Then simply use the [Search API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search).

You'll be needing a valid user access token with the API call-

```
/search?q={group-username}&type=group
```

Example: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=progressivenagars&type=group&access_token={access-token}

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer!
Your solution indeed works, but only for some of the groups. And that is the real problem. For example - it won't work for the group 'dirotTA' (Link: https://www.facebook.com/groups/dirotTA).
The reason is probably because there is a user with that name exactly, and the result is the id of that user...

Comment: I'm not sure  but I think that's best what you can do! Since graph api wont give any results directly using the username unlike user's username

Comment: Well there must be a way because for example: lookup-id.com does that, and also other websites as well...

Comment: Well these sites are probably just parsing the webpages and nothing else, since these sites objective is just to get you the id; and parsing is not a big job. As far as what seems to me, using the graph api that's what you can do!

Comment: Any idea on how they are parsing the webpages ? I can't get the source code of the page since it sends me to the login screen when i'm trying.